# How to detect when a element is on/out of the view with Next and Typescript?

Tags: jquery, typescript, next.js

I am building an app with Next and Typescript, the app has a nav bar on top of the screen, and need it to change style after a certain point of the view, I have been trying to use jQuery to achieve that result, but the whole *window is undefined* on dev mode and Typescript weird interactions with jQuery have been a problem. This is how the code looks like:

```
const Home: NextPage = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <nav id="myNav">
        <ul>
          <li>Item 1</li>
          <li>Item 2</li>
          <li>Item 3</li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
      <main>
        <div id="firstDiv">
         {//more code}
        </div>
        <div id="divToHideNav">
         {//more code}
        </div>
      </main>
    </>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

How can I change the nav style when it gets to the second `div`? I'm looking for any solution, with or without jQuery. Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you want to change style after a certain point of the view, you can use Intersection Observer API and its polyfill (for internet explorer support). It will give you what you want. Take a look at here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API

Comment: @oakar would that work? I just ran a few tests and *document* is going to be undefined, the same way *window* is when I try to use jQuery

Comment: yes it will definitely work. what you are missing is, you are building an isomorphic app. so window and document will be undefined at server-side. you need to run your intersection observer callback inside of a useEffect or useLayoutEffect @placementw

Comment: this tutorial might help, i did not watch it but it seems like explains all https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QD4GcZJObXg

Comment: @oakar thanks to that I think I'm onto something here, appreciate it. If you submit that as the answer, I'll choose as the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to change style after a certain point of the view, you can use Intersection Observer API and its polyfill (for internet explorer support). It will give you what you want. Take a look at here developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/… –

what you are missing is, you are building an isomorphic app. so window and document will be undefined at server-side. you need to run your intersection observer callback inside of a useEffect or useLayoutEffect

this tutorial might help, i did not watch it but it seems like explains all youtube.com/watch?v=QD4GcZJObXg